# Express default sessions and load balancers

Tags: node.js, session, express

If I am using the default express session store with the same keys on different web servers behind a load-balancer will I need sticky sessions for them to work?

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Or will I have to use a persistent store like Redis? I do not want to use sticky sessions.

Comment: The default is an in-memory store so you would have to use a data store like Redis if you are using multiple machines (or sticky sessions)

Comment: you will need persistent session store for sharing data between different web servers. As single redis instance can serve 4gb of data from memory...it will be a better choice..

Comment: memcached or redis work well for session storage

Comment: Can I not store it in a cookie?